# Smarty template and if statement based on variable that can be an array

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to write an if statement based on the variable that can be an array.

This variable outputs category ids that each product has.

I can display them all using:

```
{foreach from=$iCat item=cat}
    {$cat.category_id}
{/foreach}
```

I want the if statement to be based on the category id.

```
{if $iCat contains(out of multiple numbers) 10}
  Do something
```

The problem is that the variable returns multiple values and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable, initialize it with `false`, then update it to `true` if the condition is met.

```
{assign var=doTheThing value=false}
{foreach from=$iCat item=cat}
    {if $cat.category_id==10}
        {assign var=doTheThing value=true}
        {break}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Does the variable doTheThing contains the thing that I want to do? How do I assign it? I just want a a simple html paragraph to be displayed.

Comment: It’s just a boolean flag - you use it in an if statement later to determine whether or not to do something.